# Tradefed configurations for C++ files

Tags: android-source, android-tradefederation

This Google page describes how to create Tradefed configurations for Java files: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/fundamentals/full_example

```
<configuration description="Runs the hello world test">
    <test class="com.android.tradefed.example.HelloWorldTest" />
    <result_reporter class="com.android.tradefed.result.XmlResultReporter" />
</configuration>
```

Is there something similar for gtest-style tests with C++? Can anyone provide an example for a Tradefed configuration using test suites written in C++?